# CakePHP: Querying for the absence of an associated record

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP application that is, well, an *application* - as in, an application to attend a university. It consists of a series of forms that are each stored in a database table, along with a handful of administration tools.

Tying all the tables together is an *application* table, which stores metadata on the application. All of the various tables that make up a prospective student's application belongTo the application table - in other words, they share a one-to-one relationship.

The application allows people to walk away in the middle of completing it, and to come back later. As a consequence of this, the administration interface grows cluttered with incomplete applications. The users of the interface want to see only incomplete applications that have been completed up to a certain point. The information they want comes from required form fields in a certain table, so if a person has completed that step, the desired information will be present.

All this is to say that I need a way to filter out applications that lack a record in one of the tables associated with `applications`. The easy way to do this is to filter them out after they are returned from the database, and indeed, this is what I first tried. But, I'm not just querying, I'm using the paginator, so filtering the result set after it has been returned messes up the pagination. I need to be able to filter it out in the `conditions` parameter of the `$paginate` configuration array.

Here is the relevant controller code, including the current filtering mechanism, which works, but messes with the pagination:

```
var $paginate = array(
        'limit'=>100,
        // We want apps that are complete at the top of the list, ordered by the date they were finished.
        // We want to order incomplete apps by dateStarted because they don't have a dateFinished yet.
        'order'=>array('stepsCompleted'=>'desc', 'dateFinished'=>'desc', 'dateStarted'=>'desc'),
    );

function admin_index() {
    $this->Nsapp->recursive = 0;
    $this->Nsapp->unbindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('Essay', 'Religion', 'SpecialNeed')), false);
    $nsapps = $this->paginate('Nsapp');
    // Filter out the apps that are too incomplete to do anything about
    foreach ($nsapps as $key => $nsapp)  {
        // This fairly horrible conditional says, "If they provided us with at least one name and an email, do not filter them out"
        if ((empty($nsapp['Person']['name1']) &&
             empty($nsapp['Person']['name2']) &&
             empty($nsapp['Person']['surName'])) ||
            empty($nsapp['Person']['email']))
        {
            unset($nsapps[$key]);
        }
    }

    $this->set('nsapps', $nsapps);
}
```

So, to summarize and restate: my current pagination query returns an array of empty fields for associated tables that don't have a record. I need a way to remove results that are lacking a certain associated record, not by post-filtering (because that messes with pagination), but with the conditions parameter in the `$paginate` configuration array, but I don't know how to query for the *absence* of a record.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe some form of Left Outer Join?  I suggest just working solely on the SQL - even revamp your question to only contain the SQL.  Once you have that working, it should be easy to port to Cake.  And if you have trouble w/ that, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the filter when performing your database query.

```
function admin_index() {
    $this->Nsapp->recursive = 0;
    $this->Nsapp->unbindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('Essay', 'Religion', 'SpecialNeed')), false);
    $nsapps = $this->paginate('Nsapp');
    $this->paginate['Nsapp']['conditions'] = 
          array("not"=>array("Person.name1"=>null, "Person.name2"=>null));
    pr($this->paginate('Nsapp'));

    $this->set('nsapps', $this->paginate('Nsapp'));
}
```